# Azure Function that captures change in multiple tables

Tags: database, azure, events, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I need to capture changes to multiple tables in my database.
I've thought about using Azure Functions but the SQLTrigger only supports one table.
I know that I could create several functions for each table but the solution does not convince me.
Is there a way for the Azure Function to capture multiple tables?
I have thought about extending the SQLTrigger to support multiple tables, is that possible?
I would be open to alternative solutions.
I have thought about using Logic Apps but they only support a maximum of 10 triggers.
My database is a SQL Server.
One very important thing is that the database is in bad condition and I cannot load it with much logic.
I have thought about the following things: Azure Functions, CDC, Logic Apss.
Thank you very much for your attention

I have been researching the possible solutions that Azure or other programs provide me.

Comment: Are you just responding to multiple tables, each table changing on its own? Or do you need to aggregate the changes and act later/when the right data is collected? Perhaps you could explain the problem from the process/business POV and less technology, just to see if there's something else that could be done.

Comment: This post reflects little to no research. Please try to solve the issue and report back with why or why not the solution is not working or is not satisfiable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a time-triggered function that calls the stored procedure that joins the change tracking with all the tables(CT enabled).

Example: `CT` is enabled on tables `Product`, `Order` and `Delivery`.

Create a stored procedure that formats the rows of various tables as jSON message as one column and table name as another column.

The stored procedure output will be a table with 2 columns:

```
ChangeContent | TableName
```

Note: you can add other required columns like `change_operation` etc